# I am taken from a mine, and enclosed up in a wooden case, from which I am never let out, and yet I am used by most people. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am taken from a mine, and enclosed up in a wooden case, from which I am never let out, and yet I am used by most people. What am I?

I've been told this riddle, and so far haven't found out the answer. Can someone help me?

Comment: If only someone were to invent a wooden furnace, then the answer could be coal (taken from a mine, placed in a wooden container to be burned, used by lots of people in the form of electrical energy, never let out because consumed in the furnace...unless one counts CO2 emissions, ash, and/or other combustion byproducts).

Comment: @aroth Wooden furnace? That would be quite a marvel of engineering.

Comment: Since you never marked any of the answers as correct, I'm curious what the intended solution is now.

Answer (score 55):

Are you

> Graphite

I am taken from a mine

> Graphite mines

And enclosed up in a wooden case

> Pencils are wooden, and the core is graphite

From which I am never removed

> You never take the graphite back out

And yet I am used by most people

> Most people use pencils

Comment: This stuff is slowly removed over the lifetime of the object, until it is completely out. It also has far more uses than this, so if this is the answer, it's not a very good riddle

Comment: @Suppen The actual phrasing is "never let out". One could try to lawyer around your objection by arguing that it's not "let out" (allowed to escape under its own means) but extracted (taken out by the user). Still, I agree that the riddle isn't very satisfying if this is the answer. By the way, I don't think it's a problem that the substance has many other used: the riddle claims it's used in this way, but not that it's the _only_ use.

Comment: @Suppen    According to here:  http://goodriddlesnow.com/riddles/by/what-am-i-riddles/page:5/sort:id/direction:asc#    Pencil Lead is the correct answer...Graphite is a common name for Pencil Lead.  I agree that it is a bad riddle and a possibly un-cited one at that

Comment: I also thought of the pencil, with the reservation that the graphite is not truly "enclosed".

Comment: My first thought too,  pencil lead is a compound mixture of graphite and kaolin, both of which are mined.

Comment: @Suppen If I were removed one millimeter at a time I wouldn't consider that being released either...

Comment: Not sure if most people use it is still true.

Comment: I dunno, what percentage of people go their entire life without ever using a pencil?

Answer (score 24):

It might not be the *intended* answer, but I can see a good fit in:

> Quartz

I am taken from a mine

> Quartz is the second most abundant mineral in Earth's continental crust and it is heavily mined, both for jewel-making and for its electrical properties.

and enclosed up in a wooden case

> One very common use of quartz is in creating oscillators used in clocks. Almost every modern wooden-cased clock will contain a quartz crystal.

from which I am never let out

> If a quartz crystal is placed into a clock case, there's no reason ever to remove it again.

and yet I am used by most people

> Most people will own at least one item that contains quartz, whether it's a clock, a smartphone, jewelery, cookware...

The wording of the riddle leaves a little room for interpretation. It gives *one* way that that thing is used (in the case), but doesn't say that it's the only way, nor does it even stipulate that that's the way most people use it.

But to me this feels like a fair fit for going into the case and never being removed.

Comment: This is what I came here to offer as an answer.

Answer (score 18):

Could you simply be

> a nail

I am taken from a mine

> from mined iron

And enclosed up in a wooden "case"

> When hammered into a plank

From which I am never removed

> Or else the house / table / furniture / box / whatever would crumble

And indeed used by most people.

Answer (score 11):

Are you

> The speaker unit in a household loudspeaker

I am taken from a mine

> Steel, iron, copper, ...

And enclosed up in a wooden case

> The speaker cabinet/enclosure - typically made of wood, except for small plastic speakers or embedded ones

From which I am never removed

> You don't usually replace the speaker unit - when it's no longer good you replace the entire speaker.

And yet I am used by most people

> Most people have or make use of loudspeakers at some time - for entertainment, at parties, in clubs, at home....

Comment: I like this one, if only because it serves to demonstrates the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 7):

> Salt.

It is taken from a mine?  Check.

Used by most people?  Check. (All people, actually, which is a bit more than "most," but since "most" is a subset of "all," it's true that it is used by most people.

Enclosed in a wooden case and never removed?  Eventually.  Not for **all** people, but **enough** to make it true.

Comment: I suppose the XXXX that people used in the last few days of their life will be enclosed in that wooden case. Also, it'll leach out over time. So this seems rather tenuous.

Comment: Salt taken from a mine is rock salt. I was under the impression that the salt we consume is sea salt.

Comment: both types are available for consumption. also lake salt.

Comment: @Tim The salt you consume is mostly whatever's cheapest in your particular area. That could be rock salt or sea salt.

Comment: @Tim Where I live, salt is rock salt unless it specifically says "sea salt" on the label.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is :

> A wedding ring

Because :

> It is mined from a gold mine, most people (in the West, at least) get married and wear one, and they usually keep wearing it after they are buried in a wooden box.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> A door lock

I am taken from a mine

> The lock in an ordinary house door is usually made of steel

And enclosed up in a wooden case

> A fairly deep hole is cut into a wooden door to fit the lock, and the wood of the door encases the lock

From which I am never removed

> Internal door locks (for ordinary domestic rooms) can last pretty much indefinitely - one might replace the handles but only rarely the part inside the door.

And yet I am used by most people

> Household doors and latches are in every house, and the vast majority (internal doors at least) are wooden

Comment: I just had to remove a door lock and replace it today haha. (Deadbolt and entire handle assembly)

Comment: The Gods of Puz-El will be angry at you...... Just saying ;-)